# Replacing a foreign key by a primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I want to know how to replace a foreign value by a primary key value when both columns are of the same type.

**Table1: Users**: `user_id` `user_name`

**Table2: Followers**: `user_name` `followed_user_name`

(Assume names are unique)

I want to create a query to obtain the same thing as **Table2** but changing each `user_name` by the `id` and the `follower_user_name` by the `id`. I am confused because both are of the same type.

What I have so far:

```
SELECT 
   table1.user_id, 
   table2.follower_user_name    #This needs to be replaced
FROM table2
INNER JOIN table1
    ON table2.user_name = table1.user_name
```

PS: this is the database I am working with, I didn't design it. Not sure why they just didn't use the ids instead in the follower table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join `followers` on `users` **twice**, once for the user name and once for the followed user's name:

```
SELECT u1.id, u2.id
FROM   followers f
JOIN   users u1 ON u1.user_name = f.user_name
JOIN   users u2 ON u2.user_name = f.followed_user_name
```

Comment: I would strongly advise against relying on left-to-right column ordering to give meaning. Also you've renamed the OP's table names (might be a good thing).

Comment: @onedaywhen Those are the names given in the text of the question, although OP's cod snippet doesn't match the text that precedes it.

Answer (score 1):

I find the accepted answer a little strange: a result with two attributes of the same name?! Needless to say such a result is non-relational.

If you accept that we need to use the `rename` relational operator (called `AS` in SQL) then we can push the operation into a table expression, which will enable the use of `NATRUAL JOIN`, which keeps us relationlanders happy:

```
SELECT user_id, follower_user_id
  FROM table2
       NATURAL JOIN table1
       NATURAL JOIN 
       ( SELECT user_id AS follower_user_id, 
                username AS follower_user_name 
           FROM table1 ) f;
```